# Submit Post forms without pageloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, webforms

I have a form like so:

```
       <form id = "membershipInfo" method = "post" action = "Default.aspx" onsubmit  = "dialogSubmitForm()" \> 
            <input type = "text" id = "changeStoreDialogText" name = "ChangeLocation" value="" /> 
            <input type = "submit" id = "DialogSubmit" value = ""/> 
        </form>
```

There are times that I want the submit to cause a page load and other times that I don't want it to. Here is `dialogSubmitForm`:

```
function dialogSubmitForm() {
    //Checks to see how to submit
    if (placeHolderVisibility) {
        //Checks to ensure that the correct information was entered
        if (!isNaN($(codeChange).val()) && ($(codeChange).val()).length == 5) {
            //Submit at page load
        } else {
            //code
            //Do not submit to pageload
            return false;
        }
    }
    else //Do submit through javascript
    {
        //Code

        //Do not submit to pageload
        return false;
    }
}
```

I thought that returning false would not cause a pageload, but apparently it does. How would I prevent a pageload with a submit button?

Comment: As an aside http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ is useful reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
onsubmit  = "return dialogSubmitForm()" \>
```

this will prevent the submit if you return false in the dialogSubmitForm() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" id="DialogSubmit" value="Submit!" onclick="return false;"/>
```

this will prevent a pageload

so in your case, it would be more like this :

```
<input type="submit" id="DialogSubmit" value="Submit!" onclick="return dialogSubmitForm();"/>
```